# How to use spring boot + spring 4 Active Directory?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

I was trying to use in my spring boot app authentication mechanism using active directory. I tried using spring 4 security for that and it didn't work.

Trying to figure out what was wrong, I found a lot of mistakes in the web, and after a while solved it with the below code.

hopefully my experience will help others.

**simply create configuration class**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

        ...

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/login", "/public/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
            .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login.html")
                .permitAll()

            .logout()
                .permitAll();

    }



    @Configuration
    protected class AuthenticationConfiguration extends
            GlobalAuthenticationConfigurerAdapter {



        @Override
        public void init(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
            ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider provider=
                    new ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider(mySite.com
                            ,ldap://10.1.112.115:389/);
            provider.setAuthoritiesMapper(new MyMapper());
            auth.authenticationProvider(provider);
        }
    }

}
```

**mapper class use to set roles**

```
/**
 * Maps groups defined in LDAP to roles for a specific user.
 */
public class MyMapper implements GrantedAuthoritiesMapper {

    public MyMapper() {
    }

    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> mapAuthorities( final Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities) {

       Set<RolesEnum> roles = EnumSet.noneOf(RolesEnum.class);

        for (GrantedAuthority authority : authorities) {
            if (RolesEnum.ROLE_ADMIN.getAuthority().equals(authority.getAuthority())) {
                roles.add(RolesEnum.ROLE_ADMIN);
            } 
        }
        return roles;
    }
}
```

**and last a simple enum**

```
public enum RoleEnum implements GrantedAuthority {

    // These roles are specified in the security application context and are
    // mapped to LDAP roles by the AuthoritiesMapper
    ROLE_ADMIN("LDAP_ADMIN");

    private final String ldapGroupName;

    /**
     * @param text
     */
    private RoleEnum(final String ldapGroupName) {
        this.ldapGroupName = ldapGroupName;
    }

    public String getAuthority() {
        return ldapGroupName;
    }

}
```

**after the user is authenticate you can get his roles using
a code like that in a RestController :**

```
SecurityContext securityContext = (SecurityContext) session.getAttribute("SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT");
        Authentication auth = securityContext.getAuthentication();

        Collection<GrantedAuthority> granntedAuthorities = (Collection<GrantedAuthority>) auth.getAuthorities();

        return granntedAuthorities.contains(RoleEnum);
    }
```